# Почему Opencart не подтягивает язык

Tags: opencart

Дело вот в чем Opencart 2  при ajax запросе не подтягивает нужный язык, есть русская и англ версия, русский текст есть но при переключении и добавлении товара в корзину все тот же текст на русском

Answer (score 1):

По опыту могу сказать, что где-то в файлах представления.tpl недобросовестные разрабы оставили не локализованные строчки. Т.е. захардкодили русские выражения, не заведя на них переменные в файлах  локализации. 8/10 что так и есть.

Comment: 9/10. Хотя разрабы просто задолбались писать в 3 места одно и то же